# Sass multiple styles with same attributes

Tags: sass

Is there a quicker way to write the same style result in Sass.?

E.g without Sass:

```
bottom: auto;
left: auto;
right: auto;
top: auto;
```

With sass

```
bottom,
left,
right,
top {
    auto;
}
```

Comment: There is an old discussion to implement that in SASS. I think this feature isn't yet but you can use this mixin: https://gist.github.com/alcidesqueiroz/323fbf9ebbd9ff1834f7 to set the same value to a list of CSS properties.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not good in Sass yet but i think you can do this using mixins

```
@mixin name_of_mixin {
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
}
```

and then

```
.box { @include name_of_mixin; }
```

Take a look for example here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-the-mixin-directive/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if it will fit your exact needs, but this might be a case for a mixin.

With SCSS syntax this would be:

```
@mixin position($position) {
   bottom: $position;
   top: $position;
   left: $position;
   right: $position; }
```

You can then use the mixin with

```
div { @include position(auto); }
```

Which is equivalent to a div with each of those positioning properties set to "auto"

SASS Syntax, for completion sake

```
=position($position) {
   bottom: $position;
   top: $position;
   left: $position;
   right: $position; }
```

And usage

```
div
  +position(auto)
```

Comment: This mixin is essentially the same as one included in my favorite Sass mixin library, [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/docs/#position). Their `position()` mixin does just this. It also has lots of other that do similar things for you -- without adding a single line of CSS you didn't ask for.